# $_GET not working on my php

Tags: javascript, php, get

I Call my PHP into my javascript code, may I know why `$_GET` not working in my PHP file?

My URL is :  `localhost/img/index.php?fname=johndoe`

Javascript inside my **index.php** is :

```
<script src="uploadname.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $(\'#redactor_content\').redactor({
            imageUpload: \'uploadimage.php\',
            minHeight: 200 // pixels
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

php file **uploadimage.php**

```
<?php

    $fname=$_GET['fname'];
    $dir = '../assets/uploads/r/';
    $sysUrl = lc('sysUrl');

    $_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

    if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
    {
        // setting file's mysterious name
        $filename = $fname.date('YmdHis').'.jpg';
        $file = $dir.$filename;

        // copying
        copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

        // displaying file
        $array = array(
            'filelink' => $sysUrl.'/assets/uploads/r/'.$filename
        );

        echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));

    }

?>
```

I've used above code but when I save the file it shows blank. got nothing may I know the reason why?

Comment: Probably because files related code require POST and not GET should your form be using that method. relevant code missing.

Comment: why are the quotes in your javascript escaped?

Comment: Hi sorry,
@FuzzyTree from my previous code I set variable from my javascript what my I set quotes in my javascript

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok frend I will test thankyou

Comment: You do know get is the part of the url following the `?` such as `url?user=1` this would give you `$_GET['user'] == 1` it's not the POST, but I imagine that the `$_FILES` sort of points at the use of post and not get.

Comment: Yes @ArtisiticPhoenix I have a url like this localhost/img/?fname=johndoe

so when I done uploading my image name would be like this johndoe.201508090456

anyway thanks I will change my code later.

Comment: i still don't get variable of url of my other page but when I test gethostname I get value of my hostname but when on url still notworking

Comment: @Fred-ii- I use POST but still i can't get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the data inside `uploadimage.php` but the query string is on your request to `index.php`. You have to include it in each request you want to read it from.

e.g.

```
$('#redactor_content').redactor({
    imageUpload: 'uploadimage.php?fname=<?php echo isset($_GET['fname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['fname']) : ""; ?>',
    minHeight: 200 // pixels
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I try your code but i have an error or did i escape it wrong? Here's my code.                                                                      `imageUpload: \'uploadimage.php?fname=<?php echo isset($_GET[\'fname\']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET[\'fname\']) : ""; ?>\',`

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim — It looks like you're trying to build the whole thing as one big PHP string. You can't nest `<?php` inside a PHP string.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I got an idea and now its working thanks

I set my code like this   `imageUpload: \'uploadimage.php?_xClick='.$fname.'\',`