# $_GET not working in my website

Tags: php, get

I am new to PHP and started learning using w3cschools. I made simple GET query to get query string from URL.

```
<?php 
$string = $_GET['q'];

var_dump($string);

?>
```

I saw [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899817/get-not-working-on-my-php) But it did not help me wither. Any suggestion and guidelines would be helpful.

Comment: How does your url looks like?

Comment: Do you use .htaccess RewriteRule with query like index.php?page=your_page ?

Comment: Do print_r($_GET) to check q param is set into URL or not.

Comment: No, I dont use .htacess file. I only have index.php file. and it contains only that code.

Comment: For curiosity, what append if you do : `var_dump($_REQUEST)`; ? And what is the URL you use ?

Comment: Hi, @Suresh: helped. It seems it was wp_engine problem they said, they disable request_order for security reason. since, WP_ENGINE hosts only wordpress was their problem looks fine now. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $_GET is not working I suggest you check request order status in php.ini file.

simply call function `phpinfo()` and search for "request_order" it should be set to GP. I had same issue and this solved my problem. Check the screenshot. [image: output from phpinfo()]

Comment: Hi, suresh. I see my request_order is set to no value as well.

Comment: I had exactly same issue. which hosting is that. Check this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567004/having-utm-in-the-url-string-breaks-the-get-variable-in-wordpress

Comment: I am using wpengine too. I am planning to host my blog using wordpress.

Comment: Please do check with wp-engine. request_order is often disabled by wp-engine like shown in the post . That should solve this problem. I had same issue before.

Comment: Thanks called a minute and they recognized the issue in a minute. The post you gave me helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: Now worries. I am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following:

> mypage.php:

```
<php var_dump($_GET['q']); ?>
```

For this to work, you would need to reach the server:

"http://" + Your Server Address + "/" + The Folder + "mypage.php" + "?q=" + a value.

Then, it would output the information; Example:

`http://localhost/mypage.php?q=something`